# Error deploying imported template

Tags: deployment, template

I've imported a template from Sharepoint into Visual Studio 2012. But when I'm trying to deploy it I get this error.

"This solution cannot be activated because its functionality depends on another solution that does not exist:Kreta.TemplateArtistonEvent.wsp, Id: 851624bf-1aec-4795-b739-e9a6f3998dd3. First add the other solution to the Solution Gallery, activate that solution, and then repeat activation of this solution".

Where can I turn off projects that depends on the template. I can't find the solution manifest file. 
Greets Fabian

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the dependency of the mentioned solution.

Two location of searching in your VS project:

1. Folder "Features" --> Open Feature XY and remove "Items in the Feature" that you don't need
2. Have look at the **onet.xml** of a Site Template for example and remove the mentioned feature